# Ggplot2 alpha not working as expected

Tags: r, ggplot2

Trying to plot a time series chart with ggplot2 and using the alpha value to make the lines darkers/lighter, as per ggplot2. Got it working in 1 function but when I try with another dataset the alpha doesnt work. Guess I am calling something incorrectly bc I have the alpha variable set at 0.2 but the line still come out dark

Here is the code and some sample data

```
tsplot <- ggplot(xall, aes(x=Var1, y=value)) + 
  geom_line(size=.01) + guides(colour=FALSE) + xlab(x.lab) +ylab("Time Series")
tsplot <- tsplot + aes(alpha=alpha, group= factor(Var2)) +guides(alpha=F)
```

Sample data for xall

```
    Var1    Var2    value   alpha   row
1   1   657 0   0.2 Other Rows
2   2   657 -0.006748957    0.2 Other Rows
3   3   657 -0.00088561 0.2 Other Rows
4   4   657 0.009399679 0.2 Other Rows
5   5   657 0.020216333 0.2 Other Rows
6   6   657 0.035222838 0.2 Other Rows
7   7   657 0.038869107 0.2 Other Rows
8   8   657 0.034068491 0.2 Other Rows
9   9   657 0.044237734 0.2 Other Rows
81  1   553 0   0.2 Other Rows
82  2   553 -0.006172511    0.2 Other Rows
83  3   553 -0.004779576    0.2 Other Rows
84  4   553 0.000116964 0.2 Other Rows
85  5   553 -0.013408332    0.2 Other Rows
86  6   553 -0.003200561    0.2 Other Rows
87  7   553 0.000574187 0.2 Other Rows
88  8   553 0.025227017 0.2 Other Rows
89  9   553 0.019984901 0.2 Other Rows
241 1   876 0   0.2 Other Rows
242 2   876 0.006348487 0.2 Other Rows
243 3   876 0.020292484 0.2 Other Rows
244 4   876 0.030155311 0.2 Other Rows
245 5   876 0.02664097  0.2 Other Rows
246 6   876 0.021992971 0.2 Other Rows
247 7   876 0.015871216 0.2 Other Rows
248 8   876 0.020519216 0.2 Other Rows
249 9   876 0.017004875 0.2 Other Rows
250 10  876 0.029588482 0.2 Other Rows
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `aes` is not normally added to a plot directly (I think it can be, but can't predict its behavior); it's usually passed to the `mapping` parameter of `ggplot` or a geom.

Comment: and you should pass alpha as a parameter unless you're mapping alpha to a variable, so something like `ggplot(xall, aes(x = Var1, y = value, group = Var2)) + 
    geom_path(alpha = 0.2)`

Comment: thanks alistaire. Works like a charm! Only problem is that if I add + geom_line(size=.01) it doest work again. hmmm

Comment: Add it all in one call: `ggplot(xall, aes(x = Var1, y = value, group = Var2)) + geom_path(alpha = 0.2, size = 0.01)`, or you're drawing the lines twice. 0.01 is so small as to be invisible in most cases, but I'm going to assume it's the appropriate value for you.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `alpha` to the global aesthetic. You should also add the `group` mapping:

```
ggplot(xall, aes(x=Var1, y=value, alpha=alpha, group= factor(Var2))) + 
  geom_line(size=.01) + guides(colour=FALSE) + xlab(x.lab) +ylab("Time Series")
```

Comment: thanks but that still didnt work for me. I wonder if its bc I have NA's in some of the data, as I get a message saving removed some rows and if that messes up ggplot instructions? the plot works though

Comment: Do you want the alpha different on each line of the group(Var2)?